# Avoiding duplicate code in my nGinx configuration

Tags: nginx

I have a Wordpress website with PHP APC caching enabled where I'd like to encrypt all requests to `http://www.domain.com/wp-login.php*` and `http://www.domain.com/dashboard?action=profile`.  I'd like to force an unencrypted connection to everything else.

I can get this to work but the configuration is extremely ugly and hacked together.  My problem is I still have to pass the two strings I'd like to encrypt to the PHP engine.  There's gotta be a better way to do this instead of duplicating so much.

```
server {
    listen       443;
    ssl     on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/new/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/new/server.key;

    server_name  www.domain.com domain.com;
    root   /var/www;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \wp-login.php.* {
        ##Stuff to send requests to the PHP engine here
    }

    location ~ \dashboard?action=profile.* {
        ##Stuff to send requests to the PHP engine here
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        ##Stuff to send requests to the PHP engine here 
    }
}

server {
    listen       80;

    server_name  www.domain.com domain.com;
    root   /var/www;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \wp-login.php.* {
        ##Stuff to send requests to the PHP engine here
    }

    location ~ \dashboard?action=profile.* {
        ##Stuff to send requests to the PHP engine here
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        ##Stuff to send requests to the PHP engine here 
    }

    location ~ \dashboard/\?action\=profile$ {
        rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;    
    }

    location ~ \wp-login.php.* {
        rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;    
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't want to protect only the login pages; this doesn't reduce your vulnerability to cookie stealing attacks such as [Firesheep](http://codebutler.com/firesheep/). You have to go 100% HTTPS to mitigate this.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I thought that was why WordPress had all those random strings in the cookies? Back in the 'day you had to put those into wp-config yourself during install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as requiring SSL for login and dashboard access, there are a number of solutions. One simple one is to edit `wp-config.php` and just above the line that states `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */` add `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);`.

Personally, I don't worry about abuse of https version of a site as search engines will by default link to non-https versions of sites, so unless your users are regularly logging in, only a tiny fraction of them would be using the https version of the site, thus negligible increase in server load, but YMMV.

You might find many of the tips in this Ars Technica article, [Web Served, part 5: A blog of your own](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/12/web-served-part-5-a-blog-of-your-own/), useful.

You may also want to review the [common configuration pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/) at nginx.org.

Comment: After all that hassle over messing with the nGinX config file, I found the FORCE_SSL_ADMIN constant you referred to.  It worked like a champ.

Comment: You're welcome! You may also find the [WordPress Q&A site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/?as=1) helpful.

Answer (score 8):

to avoid nginx duplication in location blocks either use nginx includes OR use nested location blocks - A nested location block example follows ...

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://mywebfeservers;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Request-ID $uuid;
        proxy_set_header Via $via;

        location /aaa {
            # proxy_pass is not inherited, unsure about proxy_http_version
            proxy_pass http://mywebfeservers;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            # Prevent caching
            if_modified_since off;
        }
    }
```

Here all locations have these various headers set. Only the /aaa location prevents caching however BUT it still uses the same headers without repeating the config. Sadly, you DO HAVE TO repeat proxy pass since inheritance does not work with the proxy pass directive (for reasons of which I am unaware).

Comment: Since more time has passed, are you now aware if proxy_http_version (or similarly proxy_set_header ) are inherited or not?